# Difference between (a not in b) & (not a in b). Python

Tags: python

Hi can someone shed light on the mechanics of working "in" operator in Python.

I'm now dealing with examples below:

```
print ('a' not in ['a', 'b'])  # outputs False
print (not 'a' in ['a', 'b'])  # outputs False   --   how ???

print ('c' not in ['a', 'b'])  # outputs True
print (not 'c' in ['a', 'b'])  # outputs True


print (not 'a')   # outputs False
# ok is so then...
print (not 'a' in ['b', False])   # outputs True --- why ???
```

I'm now in wonder how it can be so. If someone knows, please share your knowledge. 
Thanks =)

Comment: `a not in` and `not a in` are equal

Comment: Note that the python styleguide says you should use `a not in`, even though they do the same.

Comment: you could easily change it to `(not 'a') in ['b', False]` which would give you the answer you apparently expect (since parens always denote higher precedence)

Comment: The [peephole optimizer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/peephole.c#L437) converts statements like `not a in b` to  `a not in b`. So, that's another reason to use `not in`, and it is much readable as well IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`in` has higher precedence than `not`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). As such, the containment check is performed and then the result is negated if required. `'a'` is not in `['b', False]`, and the resultant `False` is negated to result in `True`.

Answer (score 2):

the `not` keyword basically "reverses" the boolean returned here.

For the first example, `a` is in the array, so that's true, but `not true` is false. So false.

For the second example, `a` is not in the array, so that's false, but `not false` is true. So true.

Answer (score -1):

`print (not 'a' in ['a', 'b'])`

break it down like this:

`not 'a'` evaluates to `False` by itself (because anything is considered `True` except 0,None,False,empty lists, and empty dictionaries )

and `false` is not in `['a','b']` so
`False in ['a','b']` evaluates to `False`

and on the last one `not 'a'` evaluates to `False` so `False in ['b', False]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: This explanation is wrong. It doesn't keep in account the precedence of the operators.